# How Optimize Sum SQL Query?

Tags: sql

I have this query.

```
select  a.NoSPKJahit as 'TglSPKJahit',
        c.TglSPKJahit as 'spkJahit',
        a.SeriBarang as 'KodeSeri',
        b.NamaBarang as 'NamaBarang',
        a.JmlTotalPotong-a.JmlTotalRusakSablon as 'JumlahSPKJahit',
        a.JmlTotalSelesaiJahit as 'JumlahHasilJahit',
        (select sum(Qty) from PenjualanDTL where KodeBarang = a.KodeBarang) as 'JumlahPenjualan',
        (select sum(JumlahRetur) from StokBS where KodeBarang = a.KodeBarang) as 'JumlahRetur',
        (select sum(JumlahRusak) from StokBS where KodeBarang = a.KodeBarang) as 'JumlahRusak',
        (a.JmlTotalSelesaiJahit - (select sum(Qty) from PenjualanDTL where KodeBarang = a.KodeBarang) +((select sum(JumlahRetur) from StokBS where KodeBarang = a.KodeBarang)-(select sum(JumlahRusak) from StokBS where KodeBarang = a.KodeBarang))) as 'SisaBarang',
        (select sum(JumlahStok) from StokToko where KodeBarang = a.KodeBarang and KodeToko = 'GD000')as 'Gudang',
        (select sum(JumlahStok) from StokToko where KodeBarang = a.KodeBarang and KodeToko = 'GD001')as 'GudangAtas',
        (select sum(JumlahStok) from StokToko where KodeBarang = a.KodeBarang and KodeToko = 'GD002')as 'Mobil',
        (select sum(JumlahStok) from StokToko where KodeBarang = a.KodeBarang and KodeToko = 'OL01')as 'MissMode',
        (select sum(JumlahStok) from StokToko where KodeBarang = a.KodeBarang and KodeToko = 'TK005')as 'SilverLeafM'
from DetilBarang a
left join MsBarang b on b.KodeBarang = a.KodeBarang
left join SPKJahit c on c.NoSPKJahit = a.NoSPKJahit
```

but have very slow performace. How can i speed up query performance ?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you use inner(left) join or cross join from your query? It will performance a lot

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and you are using invalid standard SQL sql). Please [add a tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) for the database product you are using

Comment: Some side notes: a, b, and c are bad alias names for tables, as they are not mnemonic. Use something that reminds of the table name, such as `db` for `DetilBarang`. Single quotes are string literal delimiters. Standard name delimiters are double quotes. (Few DBMS use proprietary quotes, such as the backtick in MySQL and brackets in SQL Server.) If upper / lower case of the column names is not really important for you, I'd remove them altogether, e.g. `a.NoSPKJahit as TglSPKJahit`. I take it that you are using outer joins on purpose? If you only need inner joins, use inner joins instead.

Comment: You should create Column Indexes for your Sum columns do the work faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd move the subqueries to the join clause and use conditional aggregation (`SUM(CASE WHEN ...)` for all the `StokToko.JumlahStok` sums.

```
select
  db.NoSPKJahit as "TglSPKJahit",
  sj.TglSPKJahit as "spkJahit",
  db.SeriBarang as "KodeSeri",
  mb.NamaBarang as "NamaBarang",
  db.JmlTotalPotong - db.JmlTotalRusakSablon as "JumlahSPKJahit",
  db.JmlTotalSelesaiJahit as "JumlahHasilJahit",
  pd."JumlahPenjualan",
  sb."JumlahRetur",
  sb."JumlahRusak",
  db.JmlTotalSelesaiJahit - pd."JumlahPenjualan" + sb."JumlahRetur" - sb."JumlahRusak"
    as "SisaBarang",
  st."Gudang",
  st."GudangAtas",
  st."Mobil",
  st."MissMode",
  st."SilverLeafM"
from DetilBarang db
left join MsBarang mb on mb.KodeBarang = db.KodeBarang
left join SPKJahit sj on sj.NoSPKJahit = db.NoSPKJahit
left join
(
  select
    KodeBarang,
    sum(Qty) as "JumlahPenjualan"
  from PenjualanDTL
  group by KodeBarang
) pd on pd.KodeBarang = db.KodeBarang
left join
(
  select
    KodeBarang,
    sum(JumlahRetur) as "JumlahRetur",
    sum(JumlahRusak) as "JumlahRusak"
  from StokBS
  group by KodeBarang
) sb on sb.KodeBarang = db.KodeBarang
left join
(
  select
    KodeBarang,
    sum(case when KodeToko = 'GD000' then JumlahStok end) as "Gudang",
    sum(case when KodeToko = 'GD001' then JumlahStok end) as "GudangAtas",
    sum(case when KodeToko = 'GD002' then JumlahStok end) as "Mobil",
    sum(case when KodeToko = 'OL01' then JumlahStok end) as "MissMode",
    sum(case when KodeToko = 'TK005' then JumlahStok end) as "SilverLeafM"
  from StokToko
  group by KodeBarang
) st on st.KodeBarang = db.KodeBarang
order by db.NoSPKJahit;
```

Please change the left outer joins to inner joins where appropriate.

Recommended indexes to speed up the query:

```
create index idx1 on msbarang (kodebarang, namabarang);
create index idx2 on spkjahit (nospkjahit, tglspkjahit);
create index idx3 on penjualandtl (kodebarang, qty);
create index idx4 on stokbs (kodebarang, jumlahretur, jumlahrusak);
create index idx5 on stoktoko (kodebarang, kodetoko, jumlahstok);
```

This may be as fast as it gets. Without any `WHERE` clause you are probably querying a lot of data.

Comment: great, thanks. With my own query the completion time is 14 minutes, but with this query the completion time is just 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
SELECT A.*, sum(ISNULL(B.qty, 0)) as TotQty
from SiteInformation A
left join ItemSite B on A.SiteID = B.SiteID and A.InvtID = B.InvtID
```

I Think it will work better than TotQty = (SELECT SUM(Qty) FROM where...)